# Jquery select all children within children

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector

I'm sure this will be a simple question but I still struggle with DOM selectors in Jquery so here is a model of my html code:

```
<fieldset class="product-options" id="product-options-wrapper">
   <ul class="options-list">
      <li><a href>Item1.1</a></li>
      <li><a href>Item1.2</a></li>
      <li><a href>Item1.3</a></li>
   </ul>

   ...other html items here

   <ul class="options-list">
      <li><a href>Item2.1</a></li>
      <li><a href>Item2.2</a></li>
      <li><a href>Item2.3</a></li>
   </ul>

</fieldset>
```

Now how do I select all of the 'li a' items in both lists (or X number of lists) with class name .options-list and bind them with a click function.

Currently I have:

```
$('fieldset#product-options-wrapper ul.options-list > li a').bind('click', function(e) {
     //code here
});
```

And it only gets the first options-list.

Thanks, greatly appreciated!

EDIT: If i click on a Item2.X list item first, then it will grab that options list. But as soon as I click on the Item1.x list items it disregards the second .options-list

Comment: Works fine http://jsfiddle.net/Wk3wS/

Comment: Are you suggesting in your edit that the click function works fine for the first list you click on and then stops working for the other list? If so that implies that there is some state being set in your click function that is preventing it running properly later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to bind to each li element, you should bind it to the ul element instead (helps greatly with performance when there are a lot of events).

```
$('.options-list', '#product-options-wrapper').bind('click', function(e)
{
   e.preventDefault();//In case you don't want to go to a different page
   var clicked = e.target;//The href that was clicked
   /* If you only want this to happen if the a tag was clicked, add the following line
   if(clicked.tagName == 'A')*/
   //Rest here
});
```

Comment: That's great!  Now it gets both of them.  Before it was only selecting one of the lists when clicked on.  This handles both!  So what exactly does the comma do in the selector?

Comment: The comma in the separator just gives it a context.  It is the same as saying $('#product-options-wrapper .options-list').  I just like keeping them separate for readability.

Comment: oh that makes sense.  Alright well thank you!  Accepted Answer

Comment: It also makes the code a little more efficient (very little effect, though) by going to the id first and then searching for the class.  If you do $('#product-options-wrapper .options-list'), it will get all of the classes that are .options-list and then check that they are children of #product-options-wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

How about `$('.options-list a').bind('click', function(e) { });`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use delegate in this case to make it even simpler. Try this

```
$('#product-options-wrapper ul.options-list').delegate('li > a', 'click', function(e) {
     //code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method seems sound to me. I created a test fiddle using your HTML (and an extra anchor to prove that it won't get the click added) and your JS (with minor modifications).

http://jsfiddle.net/chrisvenus/esZxH/1/

The selector you had did work but since you said you wanted the a to be a direct child of the li (or at least I read it that way) I slightly tweaked it in my version above. ARe you sure its not just your function is not doing quite what you want while executing or can you confirm that your click function isn't being run at all?

Comment: I've confirmed by creating as simple alert.  If I click any of the first item set the alert shows.  Then If I click the second set the alert does not fire.  The only way to get the second alert is if I select that set first.  But @Kyle gave an answer above that works.  Thanks!